# How to print out the chosen tokens by players in a game with array of tokens

Tags: c, recursion

So the rules of the game sound like this:

Two players, A and B, play on a table with a row of 1 to 20 tokens each having a number on it. Players take turns, starting with A. In each turn, a player can take 1-2 tokens but cannot take two tokens in a row. The game ends when a player takes the last token. The winner is the player with the higher sum of token values. The task is to find the most efficient moves for both players and determine the winner.

The input and output should look like this:

Input:

```
-11 5 3 6 -1
```

Output:

```
Player A chose -1 with index [4]
Player B chose 6 and 3 with index [3], [2]
Player A chose 5 with index [1]
Player B chose -11 with index [0]
A: 4, B: -2
```

I was able to calculate the result and who wins but I cant find a way to print out the selected tokens chronologically.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int processInput(int elements[], int maxElements) {
    int count = 0;
    do {
        int input = scanf("%d", &elements[count++]);
        if (input == 0 || count == maxElements) {
            break;
        }
    } while (getchar() != '\n');

    return count;
}

int findSmallest4(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int smallestArr[] = {a, b, c, d};
    int smallest = smallestArr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        smallest = smallestArr[i] < smallest ? smallestArr[i] : smallest;
    }
    return smallest;
}
int findSmallest3(int a, int b, int c) {
    int smallestArr[] = {a, b, c};
    int smallest = smallestArr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        smallest = smallestArr[i] < smallest ? smallestArr[i] : smallest;
    }
    return smallest;
}
int findSmallest2(int a, int b) {
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

int findLargest4(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int largestArr[] = {a, b, c, d};
    int largest = largestArr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        largest = largestArr[i] > largest ? largestArr[i] : largest;
    }
    return largest;
}
int findLargest3(int a, int b, int c) {
    int largestArr[] = {a, b, c};
    int largest = largestArr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        largest = largestArr[i] > largest ? largestArr[i] : largest;
    }
    return largest;
}
int findLargest2(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
// Recursive function to maximize the number of coins collected by player 1,
// assuming that the player 2 also plays optimally

int findMaxCoins(int coin[], int i, int j, bool playerAPrevMove, bool playerBPrevMove) {
    // Base cases
    if (i > j) {
        return 0;
    } else if (i == j) {
        return coin[i];
    } else if (i + 1 == j) {
        if (playerAPrevMove == true) {
            return findLargest3(coin[i], coin[j], coin[i] + coin[j]);
        } else {
            return findLargest2(coin[i], coin[j]);
        }
    } else if (i + 2 == j) {
        if (playerAPrevMove == true) {
            return findLargest2(coin[i] + coin[i+1], coin[j] + coin[i+1]);
        } else {
            if (playerBPrevMove == true) {
                int firstChoice = findLargest2(coin[i], coin[j]);
                int secondChoice = 0;
                if (findSmallest2(coin[i], coin[j]) < 0 || coin[i+1] < 0) {
                    secondChoice = findSmallest3(coin[i], coin[j], coin[i+1]);
                }
                return firstChoice + secondChoice;
            } else {
                return (coin[i] > coin[j]) ? coin[i] + findSmallest2(coin[i+1], coin[j]) : coin[j] + findSmallest2(coin[i], coin[j-1]);
            }
        }
    }


    int start2 = 0;
    int end2 = 0;
    if (playerAPrevMove == true) { // in case player's 1 previous move wasn't including two coins
        int bOpt1 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 3, j, false, true); //from left
        int bOpt2 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 2, j - 1, false, true); //from left
        int bOpt3 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 1, j - 2, false, true); // from right
        int bOpt4 = findMaxCoins(coin, i, j - 3, false, true); // from right
        int bOpt5, bOpt6, bOpt7;

        // Player 2 selects option where player 1 has the least coins
        if (playerBPrevMove == true) { // in case player's 2 previous move wasn't including two coins
            bOpt5 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 4, j, false, false); // from left
            bOpt6 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 2, j - 2, false, false); // from left and right
            bOpt7 = findMaxCoins(coin, i, j - 4, false, false); // from right
        }

        if (playerBPrevMove == true) { // in case player's 2 previous move wasn't including two coins
            start2 = coin[i] + coin[i+1] + findSmallest4(bOpt1, bOpt5, bOpt2, bOpt6);
            end2 = coin[j] + coin[j-1] + findSmallest4(bOpt3, bOpt6, bOpt4, bOpt7);
        } else {
            start2 = coin[i] + coin[i+1] + findSmallest2(bOpt1, bOpt2);
            end2 = coin[j] + coin[j-1] + findSmallest2(bOpt3, bOpt4);
        }
    }


    int bOpt8 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 2, j, true, true); //from left
    int bOpt9 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 1, j - 1, true, true); //from left and right
    int bOpt10 = findMaxCoins(coin, i, j - 2, true, true); //from right
    int bOpt11, bOpt12, bOpt13, bOpt14;
    if (playerBPrevMove == true) {
        bOpt11 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 3, j, true, false); //from left
        bOpt12 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 1, j - 2, true, false); //from left
        bOpt13 = findMaxCoins(coin, i + 2, j - 1, true, false); //from right
        bOpt14 = findMaxCoins(coin, i, j - 3, true, false); //from right
    }
    int start1;
    int end1;
    if (playerBPrevMove == true) {
        start1 = coin[i] + findSmallest4(bOpt8, bOpt11, bOpt9, bOpt12);
        end1 = coin[j] + findSmallest4(bOpt9, bOpt13, bOpt10, bOpt14);
    } else {
        start1 = coin[i] + findSmallest2(bOpt8, bOpt9);
        end1 = coin[j] + findSmallest2(bOpt9, bOpt10);
    }

    // Player 1 chooses the option where he has the most coins
    int largestResult;
    if (playerAPrevMove == true) {
        largestResult = findLargest4(start1, start2, end1, end2);
    } else {
        largestResult = findLargest2(start1, end1);
    }
    return largestResult;
}


int main() {
    int coin[100];
    int maxElements = sizeof(coin) / sizeof(coin[0]);
    int n = processInput(coin, maxElements);

    bool playerAPrevMove = true, playerBPrevMove = true; // check if players previous move wasn't including 2 coins
    int maxCoins = findMaxCoins(coin, 0, n - 1, playerAPrevMove, playerBPrevMove);

    printf("Coins collected by player 1 is %d\n", maxCoins);

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Create an array that holds the move information. Then when your code finds a move, it can add it to the array.

Comment: Why `findSmallest1`, `findSmallest2`, `findSmallest3`, `findSmallest4`? Just write one method, `findSmallest`, that accepts an array and an array length. This way, it works for any number of numbers you want to find the smallest of. Writing a new function for every possible `n` is not going to get you too far.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest solution would be to use an int* to store the steps. You could alternate between an identifier for the player (e.g. 1 for A, 2 for B) and the index of the taken coin, 0 as endofstring if in even index.
Example:

```
    [1,4,2,3,2,2,1,1,2,0,0]
```

to represent

```
    [Player A, took [4] (-1), Player B, took [3], Player B, took [2], Player A, took [1], Player B, took [0], endofstring]
```

You would assign the move values as you know them, i.e. when you update your sums with the new value. You can keep track of where you are in the move array with a simple int variable.
Hope that helped :)